# Drop Down Menu List Loses Focus In IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-select

When we click on select element to get list of options and go down to select one, select loses focus. It only happens in ie (ie9).

I came across blog post of @jeffsebring http://jeffsebring.com/drop-down-menus-losing-focus-in-internet-explorer/ but he did not provided details of his solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my post wasn't clear enough, I'll review it.

The issue I was having, was the dropdown menu did not have a background at all. My solution was to give it a transparent background. I don't know why, but in IE you need a background of some sort to hold focus.

That said, if you use a drop down menu now, it should not rely on a hover state, as touch devices don't have hover.

Answer (score 0):

I was helped by @Jeff Sebring answer, but it's not only the matter of having a background, it's the matter of not having this background change on an hover state

```
 .ie div select { background:/* whatever */} 

 .ie div:hover select {/* paste same bg for ie */}


 .ie div:hover option {/* here you can change background for ie */}
```